# Emailing from a Fileshare/Network drive?

Tags: c#, email, network-drive, fileshare

I have a system of programs. Basically I have a service running on an External computer that listens to a network drive. When a new file is created it then goes to another directory(within that same network drive) and executes a program. The program is supposed to email that newly created file to me. It seems to work locally but not on the fileshare. I did some troubleshooting and i'm sure it gets to the piece of code that actually executes the Email App but I believe the Email App bombs out. Is it possible to email from a fileshare?

```
        InitilizeMailMessage();
        AddToAddressesToEmail(repo);
        AddCCAddressesToEmail(repo);
        AddBCCAddressesToEmail(repo);
        AssignEmailDetails(repo);
        ConstructMessage(repo, Flag);
      FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(URL, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileStream, SelectedFile));


        //smtp.int.cecdes.net
     SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SMTPURL);


     SmtpServer.Send(mail); //it seems to be bombing out here
```

Comment: Could you access sent emails on your mail server? If yes, you could check the status of the message and see if it bounces back and why.

Comment: also: what is `repo` ? your code seems to have a typo in the first line.  check the SmtpServer Settings too. You send with enforced SSL? Have you tried adding a Body and / or Subject? What is `SelectedFile`?  overall, give more information

Comment: did you look in the event viewer on that machine - there may be an error that indicates what issue you are facing.

Comment: @Vogel612 sorry I should've removed that. Thank you all for the trouble shooting tips. I actually don't have access to the fileshare's event log. I will get incontact with my system admin and report back. Thank you.